# Can't clone/push from GIT using IntelliJ Idea with ssh

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm trying to clone a GIT repository using IntelliJ Idea, but encounter an error.
It says:

```
21:28:57.558: cd C:\Users\myUser\Documents\IdeaProjects
21:28:57.559: git clone --progress git@git.xxx.com:qa-automation/selenium.git selenium
Cloning into 'selenium'...
fatal: 'qa-automation/selenium.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

If I copy the git command from the second line and execute it in the GIT Bash it clones the repository correctly and everything works from CLI (including commit and push).
I tried to open the cloned project in the IDEA and commit it from there, but it throws the error above again.

I'm on WIN 7 with Idea SSH client.

Comment: did you supply git with some login credentials that have since been cached? Intellij might be using its own git implementation to download

Comment: I use ssh key as a credential.

Comment: Obviously, IntelliJ IDEA isn’t using your SSH key then. You should try to find out if you can configure the key location somewhere within the IDE.